# A version of isotone projection cones

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, convex-polytopes, convex-optimization, convex-analysis, cones

We write $a \succeq b$, where both $a, b \in \mathbb{R}^n$, as a shorthand for $a_i \ge b_i$ for all $1 \le i \le n$. Let $C$ be a closed convex cone in the first orthant of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and denote by $\mathcal{P}_C(a)$ the projection of $a$ onto $C$. Is it true that, $a \succeq b$ implies $\mathcal{P}_C(a) \succeq \mathcal{P}_C(b)$? If this does not hold generally, what additional assumptions of $C$ do we need?

Thanks!

Comment: What about the projection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $C=\{y=-x\}$, with $a=(0,2)$ and $b=(0,0)$ ? It seems to prove that the general statement you were looking for is false.